# Replacing initial view of a panel with a content view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, panels, theming

I have a Panel that is supposed to show initially a **Taxonomy view** and a set of filters for a **Content view**. If the user hits any of these filters, my taxonomy view fades out and shows my content view.

Is it there any easy way of doing this, without having to create a personalized template file with some *javascript* under the hood?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so (never come across a module that would automatically replace one view with another based on filters). I suspect you'd need to build this manually

Comment: that's what I finally ended up doing. I was hoping there was a module, or a view type for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally ended up showing both views, and having them hidden depending on the status of the exposed filters via Jquery.